# Skipping indexes in for loop without me wanting it to happend

Tags: python-3.x

So I have this code:

```
lst = ["kjøres", "kjørt", "kjørende", "kjører", "kjørte", "kjørte", "kjøre", "kjørt", "kjørt", "kjørte", "kjørt", "kjør"]
soutLst = []

for i in lst:
    holder = str(i + " - index: " + str(lst.index(i)))
    if holder not in soutLst:
        soutLst.append(str(i + " - index: " + str(lst.index(i))))

    else :
        print(holder + " not in  soutLst")

print("----------")
for x in soutLst:
    print(x)
```

and I get this output:

```
kjørte - index: 4   not in  soutLst
kjørt - index: 1   not in  soutLst
kjørt - index: 1   not in  soutLst
kjørte - index: 4   not in  soutLst
kjørt - index: 1   not in  soutLst
----------
kjøres - index: 0
kjørt - index: 1
kjørende - index: 2
kjører - index: 3
kjørte - index: 4
kjøre - index: 6
kjør - index: 11
```

and as you can see it skips some indexes, any idea how I can rewrite to add all the strings in the soutLst list? I think it is because some of the elements in Lst is the same, but I can't find a workaround.

It should show all 12 elements in soutLst

Also, it just shows the same ones when I try to list the ones that does not get included in the final for statement

Comment: You can use `enumerate` to get both indexes and items when you iterate over the list @klindalen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are creating `holder` string, checking it's existence in `soutLst`, and also you have an extra `else` for not sure what reason

Instead of all this, you can use `enumerate` which provides you both the index and the value in the list when you iterate over it, and use it to make your `soutLst`

```
lst = ["kjøres", "kjørt", "kjørende", "kjører", "kjørte", "kjørte", "kjøre", "kjørt", "kjørt", "kjørte", "kjørt", "kjør"]
soutLst = []

for idx, item in enumerate(lst):
    soutLst.append(item + " - index: " + str(idx))

print("----------")
for x in soutLst:
    print(x)
```

The output will be

```
----------
kjøres - index: 0
kjørt - index: 1
kjørende - index: 2
kjører - index: 3
kjørte - index: 4
kjørte - index: 5
kjøre - index: 6
kjørt - index: 7
kjørt - index: 8
kjørte - index: 9
kjørt - index: 10
kjør - index: 11
```

Answer (score 0):

So I rewrote it and dumbed it down for myself, apparently I overcomlicated the problem:
Here is a solution that does what I wanted:

```
lst = ["kjøres", "kjørt", "kjørende", "kjører", "kjørte", "kjørte", "kjøre", "kjørt", "kjørt", "kjørte", "kjørt", "kjør"]

for i in range(len(lst)):
    print(str(lst[i] + " - index: " + str(i)))
```

Which gives this output:

```
kjøres - index: 0
kjørt - index: 1
kjørende - index: 2
kjører - index: 3
kjørte - index: 4
kjørte - index: 5
kjøre - index: 6
kjørt - index: 7
kjørt - index: 8
kjørte - index: 9
kjørt - index: 10
kjør - index: 11
```

Comment: No need to even do a `range` iteration @klindalen, just use `enumerate`, check my answer above :)

Comment: Thanks for that, decently new to Python so hadn't really looked into enumerate. It was just the way that I knew how to do it, been looking in the docs now on it and it seems like something I should use more :)

Comment: It worked perfectly, it was a simple mistake by me, thought I could set two different posts as answer. I set yours back to being the answer when I noticed the error

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh On my screen it says you are accepted

Comment: No sir, I see the green tick (accept) on your answer, perhaps you could refresh the page and check again :) @klindalen

Comment: That should do it :)

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Weird question, but I just posted another question similar to this. Would you mind taking a look if you have a minute or 4?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56148986/iterating-over-json-object-does-not-print-all-results

Answer (score 0):

I see that there are duplicates in the python list lst. Since you've given a condition:

```
if not holder in soutLst:
    soutLst.append(str(i + " - index: " + str(lst.index(i))))
```

, this will avoid appending the those duplicated items except the first occurence into the other python list soutLst. And also I recommend you to use/correct the logging as shown below:

```
for i in lst:
    holder = str(i + " - index: " + str(lst.index(i)))
    if holder not in soutLst:
        soutLst.append(str(i + " - index: " + str(lst.index(i))))
    else :
        print(holder + " already found in  soutLst")
```

Now it makes even more sense.